# Why can't one set to "False" specific axis ticklabels (ex: xlabels_top, ylabels_right) from a cartopy-geopandas plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas, cartopy

I am having serious difficulties in setting to `False` the `xlabels_top` and `ylabels_right` from my Geopandas plot.

This geopandas plot is made inside a `Geoaxes` subplot created with `PlateCarree` projection from Cartopy library.

My geopandas `Geodataframe` is in SIRGAS 2000 (units: degrees), EPSG: 4989.
Therefore I created a Geodetic Globe object from the cartopy library.

Here is a code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas as gpd

Geopandas_DF = gpd.read_file('my_file.shp')

# setting projection and Transform
Projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()
Transform = ccrs.Geodetic(globe=ccrs.Globe(ellipse='GRS80'))

Fig, Ax = plt.subplots(1,1, subplot_kw={'projection': Projection})

Geopandas_DF.plot(ax=Ax, transform=Ax.transData)

Ax.gridlines(crs=Projection , draw_labels=True, linewidth=0.5, 
             alpha=0.4, color='k', linestyle='--')

Ax.xlabels_top = False nn# It should turn off the upper x ticks
Ax.ylabels_right = False # It should turn off the right y ticks
Ax.ylabels_left = True
Ax.xlines = True

Fig.show()
```

Here is a figure example. One can notice that the xticks from the upper axis and the yticks from the right axis have not been turned OFF (`False`).

[image: Figure with xticks and yticks error]

Therefore, I would like to know whether that is a problem between Cartopy and Geopandas, or am I doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: I would like to add that options like  ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left') and 
 ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')                                                         
have already been tried without success.

Comment: Have you tried putting `Ax.xlabels_top = False` and `Ax.ylabels_right = False` after `Geopandas_DF.plot(ax=Ax, transform=Ax.transData)`?

Comment: Dear Ghost, yes, I have tried that option of yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels belong to the gridliner instance not the axes, you can turn them off there by storing the gridliner returned by the gridlines method and setting `top_labels`, `right_labels` as in:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas as gpd

Geopandas_DF = gpd.read_file('my_file.shp')

# setting projection and Transform
Projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()
Transform = ccrs.Geodetic(globe=ccrs.Globe(ellipse='GRS80'))

Fig, Ax = plt.subplots(1,1, subplot_kw={'projection': Projection})

Geopandas_DF.plot(ax=Ax, transform=Ax.transData)

gl = Ax.gridlines(crs=Projection , draw_labels=True, linewidth=0.5, 
                  alpha=0.4, color='k', linestyle='--')

# For Cartopy <= 0.17
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_right = False
# For Cartopy >= 0.18
# gl.top_labels = False
# gl.right_labels = False

Fig.show()
```

Comment: Dear Adjawson, Thank you for your reply. I applyed your code and it almost solved my problem.

Comment: Some typos: `gl.top_labels` and `gl.right_labels` should be `gl.xlabels_top` and `gl.ylabels_right`, respectively.

Comment: I was looking at the latest master of cartopy where I see top_labels etc: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/b7bafdfd89570569930b5d29a21a33d2282eef32/lib/cartopy/mpl/gridliner.py#L232. It changed recently as part of an overhaul of grid labelling. For version 0.17.0 and below @swatchai is correct, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @ajdawson This is one of a few mess in Cartopy.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve my problem. I used Ajdawson tips in order to do so. Here is the code with the solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas as gpd

Geopandas_DF = gpd.read_file('my_file.shp')

# setting projection and Transform
Projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()
Transform = ccrs.Geodetic(globe=ccrs.Globe(ellipse='GRS80'))

Fig, Ax = plt.subplots(1,1, subplot_kw={'projection': Projection})

Geopandas_DF.plot(ax=Ax, transform=Ax.transData)

gl = Ax.gridlines(crs=Projection , draw_labels=True,    linewidth=0.5, 
                  alpha=0.4, color='k', linestyle='--')

gl.top_labels = False
gl.right_labels = False
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.ylabels_right = False

Fig.show()
```

Comment: One thing I could not solve after solving this problem with my ticklabels (X and Y axis) has been its edition. I am from a Latin country, and I would need to change the decimal separator ('.') into comma (','). Since my Figure, and Axes created with Cartopy require the gridlines function in order to plot the coordinates, I can't apply normal functions to change my ticklabels. Does anyone know how to solve it? I will add a question in the Stackoverflow specifically regarding this Issue.