# How can one edit the "Text" object from the "Y" and "X" axis from a gridlined cartopy geopandas plot

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas, cartopy

This question arose from another Stackoverflow Issue [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580278/why-cant-one-set-to-false-specific-axis-ticklabels-ex-xlabels-top-ylabels/54582560#54582560):

My problem regards the edition of the X and Y axis ticklabels from a cartopy-geopandas plot. I would like to change my Text object from each of my ticklabels (X, and Y axis) according to a certain rule.

For example, I would like to change the decimal separator ('.') into comma separator (',') from my X and Y axis ticklabels.

Here is a code that can't do that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas as gpd

Geopandas_DF = gpd.read_file('my_file.shp')

# setting projection and Transform
Projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()
Transform = ccrs.Geodetic(globe=ccrs.Globe(ellipse='GRS80'))

Fig, Ax = plt.subplots(1,1, subplot_kw={'projection': Projection})

Geopandas_DF.plot(ax=Ax, transform=Ax.transData)

gl = Ax.gridlines(crs=Projection , draw_labels=True, linewidth=0.5, 
                  alpha=0.4, color='k', linestyle='--')

gl.top_labels = False
gl.right_labels = False


### Creating a function to change my Ticklabels:

def Ticker_corrector(ax):
        """
    Parameter:ax, axes whose axis X and Y should be applied the function

        """


    ## Correcting the Axis X and Y of the main Axes

        Xticks = ax.get_xticklabels()

        for i in Xticks:
            T = i.get_text()
            T = T.replace('.',',')
            i = i.set_text(T)

            print(T)

        ax.set_xticklabels(Xticks)



        ## Correcting the Axis Y

        Yticks = ax.get_yticklabels()

        for i in Xticks:
            T = i.get_text()
            T = T.replace('.',',')
            i = i.set_text(T)

            print(T)

        ax.set_yticklabels(Yticks)

        return ax

Ax = Ticker_corrector(Ax)

Fig.show()
```

One interesting part of the code above is that it runs without problem. The Python does not indicate any error in it, and it plots the Figure without any error warning.

Nonetheless, the Ticklabels are kept unchanged. Therefore, I need help with that problem.

I thank you for your time.

Sincerely yours,

Comment: `ax.set_yticklabels(Yticks)` just wants a simple list of text

Comment: Dear Paul H, thank you for your reply. I tried your option, but for some reason unknown to me, my Geoaxes Geopandas plot did not change its yticklabels. I simply couldn't solve it by normal means. The only solution I found is presented below (though it may not work forever and for every case scenario).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution. It may not work always, but it certainly solved my problem.

The fundamental basis for the solution was to set the "Locale" of my matplotlib before creating my plot.

Here is an example:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "Portuguese_Brazil.1252")
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_locale'] = True


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas as gpd

Geopandas_DF = gpd.read_file('my_file.shp')

# setting projection and Transform
Projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()
Transform = ccrs.Geodetic(globe=ccrs.Globe(ellipse='GRS80'))

Fig, Ax = plt.subplots(1,1, subplot_kw={'projection': Projection})

Geopandas_DF.plot(ax=Ax, transform=Ax.transData)

gl = Ax.gridlines(crs=Projection , draw_labels=True, linewidth=0.5, 
                  alpha=0.4, color='k', linestyle='--')

gl.top_labels = False
gl.right_labels = False


Fig.show()
```